# How to redirect other page after successfully login by a class on WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, class

- I have a WCF and my classes are on it.(as a sample Login class)

  - and I have a other app with C# ,i want the users could Login by this
    app with uses WCF Login class , and the users redirect to other page
    after successfully Login. Thanks to help me.
  - and How I can define Exception  message? in class or App ?

Login class on WCF service:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public bool UserLogin(Login userL)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BCSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            con.Open();
            bool result = false;
            string Message;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Username,Password FROM Users where Username=@Username and Password=@Password", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", userL.Username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", userL.Password);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    result = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = false;
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Code behind other App

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client objServiceClientobjService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Login UserLogin = new Login();
            textBox1.Text = UserLogin.Username;
            textBox1.Text = UserLogin.Password;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code in you button1_Click();

```
   Login UserLogin = new Login();
   UserLogin.Username = textBox1.Text;
   UserLogin.Password = textBox2.Text;
   if(objServiceClientobjService.UserLogin(UserLogin))
         {
               Response.Redirect("Home.html"); // your page to go after valid user login
         }
     else
         {
             // show error code
         }
```

Comment: have you created Data and service contract properly ? What is error ?

Comment: The parameterized query '(@Username nvarchar(4000),@Password nvarchar(4000))SELECT Userna' expects the parameter '@Username', which was not supplied